# set sibling element's value as current element's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to set a checkbox input's value as equal to value of it's sibling select option.

HTML:

```
<select name="team[]" class="form-control team" id="team">
    <option></option>
    <?php foreach ($teams as $team): ?>
        <?php
           $selected = '';
           if (isset($edit)):
           $selected = (in_array($team->id, $availableTeams)) ? ' selected' : '';
           endif;
        ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $team->id; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $team->title; ?></option>

   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>

   <label>Lead</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="lead_check[]" value="">
```

Option values in select option are populated dynamically using loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click","#team",function(){
    $("input[name='lead_check[]'").val($(this).val());
  });
  $("#team").trigger("click"); //For setting first time value on page load.
});
```

It will set selected options value to the checkbox on select box click event.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this to run on page load, here is an example of doing so:

```
$(function() {
  $("input[name='lead_check[]']").attr('value', $("select[name='team[]']").val());
});
```

This will take the value of the selected option from the dropdown, and will set it as the value of the checkbox.